# How do I print the letters and numbers of regex findall() list? Used for detecting password

Tags: python, regex, passwords

I am currently doing the one of the practice projects on Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, specifically the Password Detection project in chapter 7. And I am trying to print out the elements of the password given by the user using findall() function, but it keeps popping up that ('list has no attribute group')

I tried putting the the passPut.group(0) in a variable and printed it with the %s replacement. I tried converting it to a string by doing print(str(passPut.group(0))). And so far, the error keeps popping up

```
passwordRegex = re.compile(r'''
    ([a-zA-Z]){1,}
    ([0-9]){1,}
''', re.VERBOSE)

while False == False:
    passPut = str(input("Please input the password you would like to test: "))
    if len(passPut) <= 7:
        print("Password length too short, please try again.")
        input("Press enter to continue: ")
        continue
    else:
        break

passTest = passwordRegex.findall(passPut)

print(passPut, "is your password")

print('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, passPut.group())))

print(len(passTest.group(0)))

print(passTest.group(0))

for  i in passTest.group(0):
    print(i)
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'

That's the thing I keep seeing

Comment: Did you mean `passTest.group(0)`?

Comment: @RobertPrice oh right. Sorry. I'm gonna edit that one fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` finds all the matches in the string and return a list of all matches and if you are using groups then it will return a list of tuples. so for group 1 in first match you can try `passTest[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

passwordRegex = re.compile(
    r"""
    ([a-zA-Z]){1,}
    ([0-9]){1,}
    ([a-zA-Z0-9])*
    """,
    re.VERBOSE,
)

while True:
    passwd = input("Please input the password you would like to test: ")
    if len(passwd) >= 8:
        break
    print("Password length too short, please try again.")
    input("Press enter to continue... ")

passwd_parts = passwordRegex.match(passwd)

print(passwd, "is your password.")

print("chars:", "[%s]" % ", ".join(map(str, passwd_parts.group())))

print("Length of group 0:", len(passwd_parts.group(0)))

print("Group 0:", passwd_parts.group(0))

for i in passwd_parts.group(0):
    print(i)
```